# Как сделать так, чтобы StreamWriter сам создавал себе отсутствующую директорию

Tags: c#

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path,true, Encoding.Default))
{
    sw.Write("Hello");
}
```

У меня есть только путь `path`, допустим `F:\New\text.txt`. Папки `New` не существует. При запуске ругается на то, что нету директории. Если ее добавить - работает. Пилить строку не хочется. Нельзя как-то заставить `StreamWriter` создавать нужные директории автоматически?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Никак, он такое не умеет.

Зато можно вот так.

```cs
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)); // создает каталог, если его нет.

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
    sw.Write("Hello");
}
```

Так же изучите класс [Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netcore-3.1), там много всякого полезного.

Кстати, вместо `SteamWriter` попробуйте `File.AppendAllText()` или `File.AppendAllLines()`. Возможно станет удобнее. Методы на вход принимают строку и массив строк соответственно.

Избегайте использования `Encoding.Default`, так как кодиравка по умолчанию на одном компьютере может быть одна, на другом - другая, и в результате файл, записанный на одной машине может быть некорректроно прочитан на другой.

Без явного указания кодировки, файл будет записан в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM.

Comment: Нет доступа к директории, если использовать CreateDirectory. Ругается StreamWriter.

Comment: @VillyFiki значит вы что-то делаете не так, проверьте, что возвращает `Path.GetDirectoryName(path)`, и создается нужный ли каталог. И там ли где нужно он создается.

Comment: @VillyFiki обновил ответ, обратите внимание на важные дополнения.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал FileInfo and DirectoryInfo

Comment: @mik.ov `CreateDirectory` возвращает `DirectoryInfo`, только зачем это? Как воспользоваться вашим советом?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-5.0 примерно так :)

Comment: @mik.ov `CreateDirectory()` создает директорию, если ее еще нет, или ничего не делает, если есть. То есть проверка `Exists` избыточна. А так да, можно и `DirectoryInfo` использовать аналогичным образом.